# Change Palette color index in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, color-palette

I got [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cq0X.jpg)
The image is PNG, in mode P, palette is mode RGB.
I need to stay with 16 colors, as I want the image as 4bpp.
And I need to change his palette, making the color pink (255, 192, 203) its first index.

The image palette is:

```
{(255, 255, 232): 0, (255, 192, 203): 1, (210, 204, 147): 2, (62, 214, 108): 3, (59, 193, 95): 4, (209, 174, 99): 5, (194, 164, 92): 6, (130, 186, 185): 7, (180, 148, 83): 8, (95, 152, 121): 9, (49, 161, 88): 10, (157, 123, 59): 11, (118, 97, 55): 12, (52, 128, 119): 13, (73, 80, 63): 14, (63, 59, 47): 15}
```

And I want:

```
{(255, 192, 203): 0, (255, 255, 232): 1, (210, 204, 147): 2, (62, 214, 108): 3, (59, 193, 95): 4, (209, 174, 99): 5, (194, 164, 92): 6, (130, 186, 185): 7, (180, 148, 83): 8, (95, 152, 121): 9, (49, 161, 88): 10, (157, 123, 59): 11, (118, 97, 55): 12, (52, 128, 119): 13, (73, 80, 63): 14, (63, 59, 47): 15}
```

I made this code for it:

```
def change_palette(im):
    colors = im.palette.colors #get colors from palette
    if(PINK not in colors): #check there is pink (could be possible that there is not)
        return
    first = list(colors.keys())[list(colors.values()).index(0)] #colors is a dict so I get the key of the first index
    colors[first] = colors[PINK] 
    colors[PINK] = 0 #change the value of the colors
    newcolors = {}
    newcolors[PINK] = colors.pop(PINK)
    for key in colors:
        newcolors[key] = colors[key] #reorder the dict so it is in order
    colors = newcolors
    newcolors = []
    for key in colors: 
        for c in key:
            newcolors.append(c) #make it a list
    im.putpalette(newcolors) #change palette
```

But it makes the image look [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnBgJ.jpg)

I tried it with other methods, like not using the putpalette and changing only the colors of the palette, but that does not make any change when I save the image.
I understand the problem, but I can't seem to find a solution.
I want it to look exactly the same, but with the color pink (255, 192, 203) in the first index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep the image unchanged, and replace the index of the pink color to be `0`.

When we modify the palette, we are switching between the two colors:
All the pixels with color `(255, 255, 232)` are switched to pink color `(255, 192, 203)`, and all the pixels with pink color `(255, 192, 203)` are switched to color `(255, 255, 232)`.

The reason is that the (index) values of the pixels are not changed.
After applying the new palette, all the pixels with (index) value `0` turned to be pink, and all the (index) value `1` turned to be `(255, 255, 232)`.

For fixing that, we have to switch the image data as well (assuming pink color index equals 1):

- All the pixels with (index) value `0` should be modified to be value `1`.
- All the pixels with (index) value `1` should be modified to be value `0`.

For convenience we may convert the data to NumPy array, and convert back to PIL Image:

```
pink_index = colors[PINK]  # Original index of pink color

... 

indexed = np.array(im)  # Convert to NumPy array to easier access.
new_indexed = indexed.copy()  # Make a copy of the NumPy array
new_indexed[indexed == 0] = pink_index  # Replace all original 0 pixels with pink_index
new_indexed[indexed == pink_index] = 0  # Replace all original pink_index pixels with 0
new_im = Image.fromarray(new_indexed)  # Convert from NumPy array to Image.
new_im.putpalette(newcolors)  # Set the palette
```

---

Complete code sample:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

PINK = (255, 192, 203)

def change_palette(im):
    colors = im.palette.colors #get colors from palette
    if(PINK not in colors): #check there is pink (could be possible that there is not)
        return
    first = list(colors.keys())[list(colors.values()).index(0)] #colors is a dict so I get the key of the first index
    pink_index = colors[PINK]
    colors[first] = colors[PINK] 
    colors[PINK] = 0 #change the value of the colors
    newcolors = {}
    newcolors[PINK] = colors.pop(PINK)
    for key in colors:
        newcolors[key] = colors[key] #reorder the dict so it is in order
    colors = newcolors
    newcolors = []
    for key in colors: 
        for c in key:
            newcolors.append(c) #make it a list
    #im.putpalette(newcolors) #change palette

    indexed = np.array(im)  # Convert to NumPy array to easier access https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023875/4926757
    new_indexed = indexed.copy()  # Make a copy of the NumPy array
    new_indexed[indexed == 0] = pink_index  # Replace all original 0 pixels with pink_index
    new_indexed[indexed == pink_index] = 0  # Replace all original pink_index pixels with 0

    new_im = Image.fromarray(new_indexed)  # Convert from NumPy array to Image https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258561/4926757
    new_im.putpalette(newcolors)  # Set the palette

    return new_im


img = Image.open('original_image.png')

new_image = change_palette(img)

new_image.save('changed_image.png')
```

---

Result:
[image]